How plausible is the etymology that dialectal Croatian "kupan(i)ja" (friend) comes from Latin *companio?
Does the Croatian dialectal word "kupan(i)ja" (company) really come from Latin *companio? What is the phonological development? 'om' was borrowed as nasal 'o' and changed to 'u', but 'a' was not affected by the change from short 'a' to 'o'. Isn't that anachronistic?
Sure, the 'a' in Latin *companio would have been long, but, as far as I understand it, we can be reasonably certain that Vulgar Latin didn't differentiate between long 'a' and short 'a', because in no modern Romance language does the outcome of Latin 'a' depend on whether it was long or short in Classical Latin.
Or is perhaps "kupan(i)ja" of Slavic origin, related to words such as "skupa" (together) or "kupiti" (gather)?

@IlyaDaskevics Sorry, I don't speak a word of Russian.

The loan hypothesis is certainly not completely straightforward, but does seem better than a native derivation.

A native derivation from kùpъ "mound" (ultimately whence skupa & kupiti) gives a plausible first syllable, but struggles to explain the suffix. Slavic *-nьje has plausible semantics, but you'd need to explain the change to a feminine from a neuter, and the medial a rather than expected i (as a deverbal suffix, -nьje retains the -i- seen in the verb).

Looking at it as a loan:
As you say, borrowing the Latin /om/ (perhaps actually [õ]) as Slavic *ǫ makes the development regular, as *ǫ later raised to /u/ in Serbo-Croatian, Czech, Slovak, and East Slavic.
PIE short *a and *o had already merged in Proto-Balto-Slavic, and this merged phoneme seems to have already been rounded by Middle Common Slavic.
As such, provided (Late) Latin compānia entered (dialectal) Slavic after the rounding of Proto-Balto-Slavic short *a to Middle Common Slavic *o, and before the raising of Proto-Slavic *ǫ to u, then this adaptation is entirely expected. Dating this shift in specific dialects is difficult, but note that Old Church Slavonic preserves nasalisation (and the length distinction on the nasal vowels) where it is otherwise lost throughout (almost) all of South Slavic, suggesting it may postdate early Old Church Slavonic (~9th century).
That time window is quite large, and includes the period of Slavic expansion into the (previously Latin-speaking) Western Balkans.
The problem of course, is that we wouldn't expect a word meaning "company" (in the modern sense) to have existed prior to the development of modern companies, which certainly took place after the raising of Proto-Slavic *ǫ to u.
There are two explanations as to how this could still be loaned from Latin compāniō.

That it was loaned earlier, in a different sense, and underwent a parallel semantic development to that in English, likely under influence of the many other European languages where words in the same word family mean "company".
That it was loaned after the semantic development, but adapted on the model of earlier loans where Latin/Romance /oNC/ appears as /uC/.

It seems unlikely that a word that is dialectally restricted would have undergone such an areal semantic development, so the first explanation doesn't seem very good. The second however is entirely plausible, provided other such loans are plentiful, and readily identifiable as Latin/Romance loans to speakers of dialects where the word is found.

So yes, it likely is an anachronistic adaptation, probably influenced  by other earlier loans where Latin/Romance /oNC/ appears as /uC/.

I don't know what exactly "kupanija" means. I am not sure it even can refer to company in the sense "small corporation". I think it means more like "group of friends".

@FlatAssembler ah, in that case I don't think there's even any need to invoke an anachronistic adaptation. It could have entered the language in the period when Slavic first arrived in the Western Balkans in which case the adaptation is entirely as expected
